# Angular - on button click run function in different component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a simple task in Angular but it's giving me some trouble.

I have 2 separate components with no relation between them, let's call them **Component A** and **Component B** - all I want is that when I press a button in **Comp A** to run a function in **Comp B** - the onClick event and corresponding function is already sorted, I just need to call a function that's coming from **Comp B** like in the example below:

**Component-A.component.ts**

```
onButtonClick() {
  //do something
  //call function from Comp B

  functionB();
}
```

**Component-B.component.ts**

```
functionB() {
  element.scrollTo({top: 0})
}
```

All I want is to call the function from **Comp B** inside the onClick function of my button from **Comp A** so that the container of **Comp B** is scrolled to top.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Create a service which has a subject and inject in both the components. Do these 2 things:

1. in component B, subscribe to the subject
2. in component A, set the subject inside the function which you want to call

make sure to unsubscribe from the subject

one good example can be found here: https://medium.com/mobiosolutions/angular-communicating-between-components-with-observable-827180e43eb5

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of the components you could use an [EventEmmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). Assuming you can refactor to this structure:

```
<parent-component>
  <component-a (clicked)="onComponentAClicked()"></>
  <component-b #compB><>
</parent-component>
```

The `parent-component` can listen for the `component-a` `click` event to be emitted. It can then call the public `scrollToTop` function on `component-b` by refencing the [ChildView](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

*commponent-a*

```
<button (click)="onButtonClick()">Click here</button>

...
export class ComponentA {
  @Output('clicked') public clicked = new EventEmitter();

  public onButtonClick() {
    this.clicked.next(true);
  }
}
```

*parent-component*

```
...
export class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChild('compB') public compB: ComponentB;

    public onComponentAClicked() {
      this.compB.scrollToTop();
    }
}
```

If you can't refactor to the above structure then as others suggested; a shared service would solve the issue. In the service you could consider adding a [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) and then subscribe to changes in `component-b`.

*component-a*

```
onButtonClicked() {
    this.scrollService.scrollToTop$.next(true);
}
```

*component-b*

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.scrollService.scrollToTop$.subscribe(() => this.scrollToTop());
}
```